# Is this a scam?

Tags: savings, scams, sugar-daddy

I have recently found some sugar daddy’s saying there will help me financially they state that they will give me a weekly allowance if I’m loyal but once I send my PayPal link they say that to authorise my payment I have to buy a 100$ gift card I ask why and they explain and they show me proof of other sugar babies who have bought the gift card and they have received the money  also but I’m not sure whether to do it or not incase I lose Money.

Comment: Do not do it. It is a scam. You will lose the money.

Comment: Worse than just a scam, this may be money laundering.

Comment: Someone who wants to give you money will not ask you to pay for it. Simple as that. As soon as they ask for money, you know they will rip you off in some way.

Comment: Why in Heaven's name would a guy want a Sugar Baby that he can't get some sugar from?  (And "to authorise my payment I have to buy a 100$ gift card" if laughable.)

Answer (score 11):

If it looks like a scam and smells like a scam; yes it’s a scam.

Comment: Nice paraphrase of the Duck Theorem.